# Python rounding with Decimal module to specified decimal places

Tags: python, math, decimal, rounding, fixed-point

**Question:** How could I make Python's Decimal module round to a specified decimal place instead of rounding to a specified precision (significant figure) while evaluating an arithmetic operation?

### Info

I have been using the Decimal module in Python to round values to a specified precision using the `setcontext` method. This works well until we start crossing whole numbers and decimals because significant figures do not differentiate between the two.

```
import decimal as d
from math import pi

decimal_places = 0
d.setcontext(d.Context(prec=decimal_places+1, rounding=d.ROUND_HALF_UP))

# This works fine
num = pi
print(f"Rounding {num} to {decimal_places} decimal places:")
print(f"Traditional rounding (correct): {round(num, decimal_places)}")
print(f"Decimal rounding (correct): {+d.Decimal(num)}")

# This is were issues start to arise
num = pi/10
print(f"\nRounding {num} to {decimal_places} decimal places:")
print(f"Traditional rounding (correct): {round(num, decimal_places)}")
print(f"Decimal rounding (incorrect): {+d.Decimal(num)}")
```

```
Rounding 3.141592653589793 to 0 decimal places:
Traditional rounding (correct): 3.0
Decimal rounding (correct): 3

Rounding 0.3141592653589793 to 0 decimal places:
Traditional rounding (correct): 0.0
Decimal rounding (incorrect): 0.3
```

### Use case

Why even use the decimal module over Python's round function? Well the advantage of the decimal module is that it would apply that precision cap in all steps of arithmetic evaluation (PEMDAS).

For example if I wanted to round x as it gets evaluated in the function I could just do:

```
function_str = "0.5 * (3*x) ** 2 + 3"
eval(function_str.replace("x", "(+d.Decimal(x))"))
```

A more complete (and simpler) example:

```
import decimal as d

decimal_places = 0
d.setcontext(d.Context(prec=decimal_places+1, rounding=d.ROUND_HALF_UP))

numerator = 5
denominator = 1.1
num_err = 0.5
new_num = numerator + num_err

print(f"Rounding {numerator}/{denominator} to {decimal_places} decimal places:")
print(f"Traditional rounding (incorrect): {round(new_num, decimal_places)/denominator}")
print(f"Decimal rounding (correct): {+d.Decimal(new_num) / d.Decimal(denominator)}")
```

```
Rounding 5/1.1 to 0 decimal places:
Traditional rounding (incorrect): 5.454545454545454
Decimal rounding (correct): 5
```

It may still seem like round would be a simpler solution here as it could just be placed around the output, but as the complexity of the function increases the less and less viable this becomes. In cases were the user enters the function the viability of traditional rounding is practically zero while using the decimal module is as simple as `function_str.replace("x", "(+d.Decimal(x))")`.

Note that the `quantize` method will not be a viable option as it only rounds the current number instead of everything (which is what setting the context precision does).

Comment: It sounds like you want to do fixed-point arithmetic, while `decimal` is a floating-point library. If you want to do fixed-point math, you may be best off just working in terms of integers and handling the scaling yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I thought the decimal module was for fixed-point arithmetic "Decimal fixed point and floating-point arithmetic" (https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html). Would you mind giving me an example?

Comment: The docs say that, but really, everything the `decimal` module does is floating-point. If you check the [faq section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal-faq), you'll see that emulating fixed-point basically involves sticking a bunch of `quantize` calls everywhere, which is an option you already discarded as non-viable.

Comment: (Even with `quantize`, the abstraction leaks - for example, if the result of an operation is too large, it may lose precision, which cannot be recovered with `quantize`. Some results may also be incorrectly rounded due to problems with double rounding unless you're very careful about rounding handling)

Comment: So what you're saying is that the decimal module doesn't support this functionality and that I need to build my own fixed-point library if I want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this I ended up just making my own fixed-point arithmetic library. To help out anyone else who runs into this problem in the future I posted the code for my fixed-point arithmetic library below.

```
import math


PREC = 0


def no_rounding(x, *args, **kwargs):
    return x


def ceil(x, prec=0):
    mult = 10 ** prec
    return round(math.ceil(x * mult) / mult, prec)


def floor(x, prec=0):
    mult = 10 ** prec
    return round(math.floor(x * mult) / mult, prec)


rounding = {
    None: no_rounding,
    "round": round,
    "ceil": ceil,
    "floor": floor,
}


class Fixed:
    def __init__(self, number, round_function="round", custom_prec=None):
        self.val = float(number)
        self.round_str = round_function
        self.round_func = rounding[round_function]
        self.custom_prec = custom_prec

    def _dup_fixed(self, number):
        return Fixed(number, self.round_str, self.custom_prec)

    def _operation(self, op):
        return self._dup_fixed(self.round_func(op, self.prec))

    @property
    def prec(self):
        return int(self.custom_prec if self.custom_prec is not None else PREC)

    @property
    def num(self):
        return self.round_func(self.val, self.prec)

    @property
    def real(self):
        return self

    @property
    def imag(self):
        return Fixed(0)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == "val":
            value = float(value)
        self.__dict__[name] = value

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.num)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.num)

    __repr__ = __str__

    def __format__(self, spec):
        if spec == "":
            return str(self)
        else:
            return spec % self.num

    def __reduce__(self):
        return (self.__class__, (self.val,))

    def __copy__(self):
        return self.__class__(self.val)

    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        return self.__copy__()

    def __pos__(self):
        return self

    def __neg__(self):
        return self._dup_fixed(-self.val)

    def __abs__(self):
        return self._dup_fixed(abs(self.val))

    def __round__(self, n=None):
        return self._dup_fixed(round(self.val, n))

    def __floor__(self):
        return self._dup_fixed(math.floor(self.val))

    def __ceil__(self):
        return self._dup_fixed(math.ceil(self.val))

    def __int__(self):
        return int(self.num)

    def __trunc__(self):
        return math.trunc(self.num)

    def __float__(self):
        return float(self.num)

    def __complex__(self):
        return complex(self.num)

    def conjugate(self):
        return self

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.num == float(other)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self == float(other)

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.num > float(other)

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.num >= float(other)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.num < float(other)

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.num <= float(other)

    def __bool__(self):
        return self.num != 0

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self._operation(self.num + float(other))

    __radd__ = __add__

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self + -other

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return -self + other

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self._operation(self.num * float(other))

    __rmul__ = __mul__

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        return self._operation(self.num / float(other))

    def __rtruediv__(self, other):
        return self._operation(float(other) / self.num)

    def __floordiv__(self, other):
        return self._operation(self.num // float(other))

    def __rfloordiv__(self, other):
        return self._operation(float(other) // self.num)

    def __mod__(self, other):
        return self._operation(self.num % float(other))

    def __rmod__(self, other):
        return self._operation(float(other) % self.num)

    def __divmod__(self, other):
        result = divmod(self.num, float(other))
        return (self._operation(result[0]), self._operation(result[1]))

    def __rdivmod__(self, other):
        result = divmod(float(other), self.num)
        return (self._operation(result[0]), self._operation(result[1]))

    def __pow__(self, other):
        return self._operation(self.num ** float(other))

    def __rpow__(self, other):
        return self._operation(float(other) ** self.num)
```

Let me know in the comments if you found any bugs or problems and I will be sure to update my answer.

#### Usage

A fixed number is created by passing the number to the `Fixed` function. This fixed number can then be treated similarly to a normal number.

```
import fixed_point as fp  # Import file

num = 1.6
fixed_num = fp.Fixed(num)  # Default precision is 0
print("Original number:", num)
print("Fixed number:", fixed_num)
print("Fixed number value multiplied by original number:", fixed_num.val * num)
print("Fixed number multiplied by original number:", fixed_num * num)
print("Fixed number multiplied by itself:", fixed_num * fixed_num)
```

```
Original number: 1.6
Fixed number: 2.0
Fixed number value multiplied by original number: 2.56
Fixed number multiplied by original number: 3.0
Fixed number multiplied by itself: 4.0
```

To set the global precision the `PREC` variable can be modified which will not only alter the precision (number of decimal places) of all new fixed precision numbers but also the existing ones. The precision of a specific fixed number can also be set during creation.

```
num = 3.14159
fixed_num = fp.Fixed(num)
custom_prec_num = fp.Fixed(num, custom_prec=4)
print("Original number:", num)
print("Fixed number (default precision):", fixed_num)
print("Custom precision fixed number (4 decimals):", custom_prec_num)

fp.PREC = 2  # Update global precision
print("\nGlobal precision updated to", fp.PREC)

print("Fixed number (new precision):", fixed_num)
print("Custom precision fixed number (4 decimals):", custom_prec_num)
```

```
Original number: 3.14159
Fixed number (default precision): 3.0
Custom precision fixed number (4 decimals): 3.1416

Global precision updated to 2
Fixed number (new precision): 3.14
Custom precision fixed number (4 decimals): 3.1416
```

Note that getting the original value of a fixed number can only be done with `fixed_num.val` using `float(fixed_num)` will return the fixed number rounded to the specified number of decimal places (unless rounding is none).